# Any non finicky way to show extra rollover info on an iphone

Tags: iphone, text, hover

I'm converting a really long survey from a web app to a mobile app.  It's 250 questions long so I've divided it into logical sections to split it up a bit.  The idea is a user is presented with a series of products from which they choose the ones they want to try.

The problem I'm facing is there is more information on product that's shown as a rollover in the web app.  This isn't possible on a mobile device so I'm wondering if anybody would have any ideas to add the extra info in.

I could make each selection on the right bigger but I don't like having different parts of a tapable area do different things.  Big fingered users won't thank me.

[image: two versions separate versions of the survey]

Answer (score 1):

When presenting multiple options on mobile, width is often the first hurdle you'll run into.

Consider a grid structure of 2 columns, and each button having an icon that expands more information below it (with a drawer-like effect). - You will also need to make sure there is a gutter between the 2 items to avoid too many miss-taps, as well as sufficient height / "breathing room" within each button.

I realise you mention not wanting to force "big finger" users into an clumsy experience, but by limiting the number of items per row to 2 and ensuring the "more info" icon tap space is sufficient - you can make sure its not - users are far more comfortable scrolling and it doesn't ruin the flow as much.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried your approach but the client pushed back and felt the first version was cleaner.  Initially I preferred the second style but I think there are pros and cons of both